# ASP.NET core running in IIS startup error logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, iis-8

How do you capture startup errors in an ASP.NET Core app hosted in IIS? I'm trying to capture exceptions thrown in `ConfigureServices` which occurs only in the IIS hosted environment.

I came across this as a certificate file loaded in `ConfigureServices` was missing and it was not captured without writing to a different log file than the application log file configured through log configuration (note that the logging system doesn't get initialised before `ConfigureServices`). In this case `stderr` would contain the exception but does IIS capture it and log it somewhere?

Comment: Why don't simply use `try` ? and log error afterward somewhere.

Comment: I'm after the "where" - EventLog only has the return code. Does IIS capture the stderr/stdout of application and log it somewhere?

Comment: locate directory where app is published, open cmd and run `dotnet YourProject.Web.dll` (startup project's dll)

Comment: thanks @tchelidze but it's not really an option.. added more details to question

Comment: which details ? question seems to be the same

Answer (score 3):

[ASP.NET Core module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module) for IIS has `stdoutLogEnabled` and `stdoutLogFile` optional parameters:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
            arguments=".\MyApp.dll" 
            stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
            stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```