# ASP.NET Core Web Project gets passed a "%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" command line argument as an unexpanded environment variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

.NET 3.1 App was working fine before but today after I tried to run it through IIS, it is giving me this error.

**given messsage error**
[image: given messsage error]

**browser shuts down after this**
[image: browser shuts down after this]

**This is how event viewer looks**
[image: This is how event viewer looks]

and also I noticed something, I'm not sure if it is important, in applicationhost.config there are lines about .Core2 (I'm using .Core 3.1)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new project and copying everything (except Program.cs and Startup) in it with some necessary configurations in Startup.cs like ConnectionString and Mapping

Answer (score 0):

You could have also enabled the [startup errors logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643054/asp-net-core-running-in-iis-startup-error-logging).
That way you would know what went wrong for the next time.